# Question with bad access issue (code enclosed below)

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hello forgive me if this is not asked correctly but I am having an issue with my code. It is an assignment for school however I am looking for help in understanding the issue not an answer so any help will be appreciated.

I will enclose the code below and upon running it gives me a an error that I do not understand. I have spoke yesterday with the teacher and he pointed me to the problem which I fixed and not it shows again.

Although there may be more errors in my code I would like to understand the bad access error first. Any help would be appreciated.

Please tell me how I could better post questions in the future as well.

error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> getVector(const string&);
string getName(const string&);
void selectionSort(vector<string>&);
bool search(const string&, const vector<string>&);
void displayResult(const string&, const string&, bool);
void writeToFile(const string&, const vector<string>&);
void reverseVector(vector<string>&);

int main()
{
    string boyName, girlName;
    bool boyNameFound, girlNameFound;


    vector<string> boyNames(getVector("BoyNames.txt"));
    vector<string> girlNames(getVector("GirlNames.txt"));


    boyName = getName("boy's");
    girlName = getName("girl's");

    selectionSort(boyNames);
    selectionSort(girlNames);

    boyNameFound = search(boyName, boyNames);
    girlNameFound = search(girlName, girlNames);

    displayResult("boy's", boyName, boyNameFound);
    displayResult("girl's", girlName, girlNameFound);

    writeToFile("Boynames_asc.txt", boyNames);
    writeToFile("Girlnames_asc.txt", girlNames);

    reverseVector(boyNames);
    reverseVector(girlNames);

    writeToFile("Boynames_desc.txt", boyNames);
    writeToFile("Girlnames_desc.txt", girlNames);

    cout<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void selectionSort(vector<string> &arr)
{

    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (arr.size() - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = arr[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < arr.size(); index++)
        {
            if (arr[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = arr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];
        arr[startScan] = minValue;
    }


}// above is code the teacher provided
// below is where I have written code for the assignment
 vector<string> getVector(const string& fileName)
{
    string name;
    ifstream file;
    vector<string> namesFromFile;
    file.open(fileName);
    while(getline(file, name))
    {
        namesFromFile.push_back(name);
    }
    return namesFromFile;
}

string getName(const string& gender)
{
    string nameChoice;

    cout << "Enter a " << gender << " name, or N if you do not wish to enter a " << gender << " name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, nameChoice);

    return nameChoice;
}

bool search(const string& nameChoice, const vector<string>& names)
{


    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        if(nameChoice == names.at(i)) // names[i]
        {

            return true;

        }

    }
    return false;
}

void displayResult(const string& gender, const string& names, bool nameFound)// change this function so either displays name found not found or chose //not to enter
{
    if(nameFound)
    {
       cout << names << "is one of the most popular " << gender << "names." << endl;
    }
    else if(!nameFound)
        cout << names << " is NOT one of the most popular " << gender << " names." << endl;

    else if(names == "N")
    {
        cout << "You chose not to enter a " << gender << " name." << endl;
    }

}

void writeToFile(const string& fileName, const vector<string>& names)
{

    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(fileName);
    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        outputFile << names[i] << endl;

    }
}

void reverseVector(vector<string>& names) 
{
    string temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = names[0];
        names[0] = names[names.size() - i];
        names[names.size() - i] = temp;
    }



}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are dereferencing a null pointer. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: in *selectionSort* you access to *arr* with invalid index, first 0 while it is empty. What about using iterator ? The size of a vector is *unsigned* so 0u-1u is not -1 so `startScan < (arr.size() - 1)` is true when *arr* empty

Comment: in *reverseVector* on the first turn *i* is 0 so you access to `names[names.size()];` withis out of the array, even you start with the index 1 you do not reverse the array when its size if at least 4

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have not tried debugging, we haven't gone over debugging so I would have to educate my self first on it. I know I can step through the program but I just dont know how to do it , unless maybe I comment everything out and bring it it in one function at a time.

Comment: @bruno the teacher had written the selection sort function so I did not change it, I just left it the way it is. However with your last comment it may have to do with my reverse vector function since that is a function I created. So if there are any more elaborations on this function I will take them and I will start to fix it. I had a hard time understanding how to reverse the vector, this is what I came up with. I look forward to any other suggestions on this function and will work on it until then. Guys, I really appreciate the quick comments as well.

Comment: Debugging is the first thing you should learn in programming. At even the basic step you can just run the debugger from your ide it will show you the line of code that is crashing

Comment: This is what I thought the reverse function did so far. Set temp to 0, after set i to 0, check to make sure i is less than the size of the vector if so run the code in the for loop, after increment i by 1 each iteration. For the code inside the for loop take name[0] which is the first index and store the value in temp, then assign the last index to the first index   ( names[0] = names[names.size()-i]), and store the temp variable which contains the value at name[0] to the last element(names[names.size() - i). Can anyone explain further or what may be the next thing for me to look at.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I will look at that now. I will go into Xcode and try to run the debugger and come back in a few

Comment: my debugger is greyed out not allowing me to select anything

Comment: @bruno is the problem the I am starting out of bounds of the vector? Should it be names[names.size() - 1 - i]?

Comment: @sjamesSchool look at my answer

Comment: @bruno I have looked at your answer and changed a few things in my code, I have commented out the selection sort function and its running but the writeToFile function is not working and I cannot display the output file

Answer (score 0):

> error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0):

That comes because of your definition of *reverseVector*, for two reasons, the first is `string temp = 0;` where you initialize your string with a `char*` being NULL with undefined behavior, just use `string temp;`

The second is on the first loop when *i* is 0 you access to `names[names.size()]` so after the last element. Out of that your algorithm is not correct with more than 3 elements in the vector because you always exchange with `name[0]`. You have to exchange `name[0]` with names[names.size()-1]`and`name[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search)`with names[names.size()-2]` etc, will go back on that function at the end of my answer

> the teacher had written the selection sort function so I did not change it

so say to your teacher his function suppose the vector is not empty, and when it is empty the test in :

> ```
> for (startScan = 0; startScan < (arr.size() - 1); startScan++)
> ```

is always false `arr.size()` returns a `size_t` which is *unsigned* so when empty that values ~0u which is the biggest possible value of `size_t`.

Say him to mix (signed) *int* and (unsigned) `size_t` is wrong, and is generally signaled by the compiler, and we are in C++, not in C, they have *iterators*.

**About *main***

To avoid the bug in *selectionSort* check the vector is non empty before to call it, so :

```
if (! boyNames.empty())
  selectionSort(boyNames);
if (! girlNames.empty())
  selectionSort(girlNames);
```

You have the special case *N* in *getName*, when the enter name is *N* you must not consider the input :

```
if (boyName != "N") {
  boyNameFound = search(boyName, boyNames);
  displayResult("boy's", boyName, boyNameFound);
}

if (girlName != "N") {
  girlNameFound = search(girlName, girlNames);
  displayResult("girl's", girlName, girlNameFound);
}
```

Note *main* do two times the same thing, one time for the boy and one time for the girl, to add a function allows to not duplicate all the code.

But it seems *main* is also written by your teacher, what a pity really.

In *getVector* may be you can produce a message when you cannot read the file. To help code reading I encourage you to add an empty line after each declaration parts, the constructor of *ifstream* allows to open the file, so you can have

```
vector<string> getVector(const string& fileName)
{
    string name;
    ifstream file(fileName);
    vector<string> namesFromFile;

    while(getline(file, name))
    {
        namesFromFile.push_back(name);
    }

    return namesFromFile;
}
```

or

```
vector<string> getVector(const string& fileName)
{
  vector<string> namesFromFile;
  ifstream file(fileName);

  if (! file)
    cerr << "cannot read " << fileName << endl;
  else
  {
    string name;

    while(getline(file, name))
    {
      namesFromFile.push_back(name);
    }
  }

  return namesFromFile;
}
```

**About *getName***

It does not manage the EOF case, nor if no name is empty or it contains only spaces, or there are spaces at the beginning and/or end.

If a name must be a unique word, so "John" buts not "John Doe" you can replace the use of *getline* by `cin >> nameChoice;`, and to force *N* if EOF :

```
string getName(const string& gender)
{
    string nameChoice;

    cout << "Enter a " << gender << " name, or N if you do not wish to enter a " << gender << " name: " << endl;
    return (!(cin >> nameChoice)) ? string("N") : nameChoice;
}
```

If a name can be composed, after the call of you have to remove spaces at the beginning and end then check if input name is empty to force *N* :

```
string getName(const string& gender)
{
    string nameChoice;

    cout << "Enter a " << gender << " name, or N if you do not wish to enter a " << gender << " name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, nameChoice);

    size_t b = 0;

    for (;;) {
      if (b == nameChoice.size())
        return "N";
      if (!std::isspace(nameChoice[b]))
        break;
      b += 1;
    }

    size_t e = nameChoice.size();

    while ((e != 0) && std::isspace(nameChoice[--e]))
      ;

    return (e >= b) ? nameChoice.substr(b, e - b + 1) : string("N");
}
```

Because there is no *iterator* in the teacher code I do not use them here and later.
Note may be you also have to remove redundant spaces into a composed name, I to replace "John   Doe" by "John Doe" ?

**About *search***

the vectors of names are sorted thanks to the call of *selectionSort*, so it is useless to search in all the vector if the name is less than a name in the vector

```
bool search(const string& nameChoice, const vector<string>& names)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
    {
        if(nameChoice == names[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (nameChoice < names[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

anyway even that small optimization your search is still in *O(N)*

You can also have a more efficient search in *O(log(N))* comparing to the half of the (sub) vectors, doing that by yourself or using [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

**About *displayResult***

*nameFound* is *true* of *false* it cannot be something else, so you cannot reach `else if(names == "N")`, you need to check that case first, and it is useless to check `if(!nameFound)` when you know `if(nameFound)` is *false*, so for instance (using *name* rather than *names* because there is only one name) :

```
void displayResult(const string& gender, const string& name, bool nameFound)// change this function so either displays name found not found or chose //not to enter
{
    if(name == "N")
      cout << "You choose to not enter a " << gender << " name." << endl;
    else if(nameFound)
      cout << name << " is one of the most popular " << gender << "names." << endl;
    else
      cout << name << " is NOT one of the most popular " << gender << " names." << endl;
}
```

or

```
void displayResult(const string& gender, const string& name, bool nameFound)// change this function so either displays name found not found or chose //not to enter
{
    if(name == "N")
      cout << "You choose to not enter a ";
    else 
      cout << name << " is" << ((nameFound) ? "" : " NOT")
       << " one of the most popular ";

    cout << gender << " name." << endl;
}
```

**About *writeToFile***

Like for *ifstream* the constructor of *ofstream* allows to open the file

You do not check if you can write in the file, this is dangerous because hide the problem, better to do for instance :

```
void writeToFile(const string& fileName, const vector<string>& names)
{
    ofstream outputFile(fileName);

    if (! outputFile)
      cerr << "Cannot open " << fileName << " to write it" << endl;
    else
    {
      for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        outputFile << names[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

**About *reverseVector***

As I said its definition is not correct, he short way is to use [std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/), else doing by yourself :

```
void reverseVector(vector<string>& names) 
{
    string temp;
    size_t pos = 0, sup = names.size();

    while ((pos + 1) < sup)
    {
        temp = names[pos];
        names[pos++] = names[--sup];
        names[sup] = temp;
    }

    for (auto s : names) cout << s << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks to everyone who helped me out on this problem. With everyones                      help I was able to understand what was going on.

@bruno helped me understand that I was trying to access out of bounds or the end of the vectors/arrays. by using the code below I was able to have store the first element in the last and the last element with the first.

void reverseVector(vector& names)

```
 {
string temp;
for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
{
    temp = names[i];
    names[i] = names[names.size() - 1 - i];
    names[names.size() - 1 - i] = temp;

}
```

} 
The original thread access error was because, although the teacher supplied

the code above the getVector function I should have understood the basic idea that I still have to change the full file path.

error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0):

```
vector<string>         boyNames(getVector("/Users/Desktop/comp165/assignment8/BoyNames.txt"));
vector<string>





 Thank you all for your help
```